# Test In-Memory collection against NHibernate restrictions

Tags: nhibernate, restrictions

My application allows a user to do some pretty in depth filter editing before they run a report. I have a whole framework to dynamically generate NHibernate restrictions based on these filters, and to run the query.

I have a situation where I have one set of restrictions for the records I want to pull, and another set of restrictions to identify records within that set that should receive special processing.

Currently the best I can do is pull both sets from the database, and as I am processing the first set I must check if the second set contains the element to see if I need to apply my special processing. The obvious problem here is that I must hit the database twice.

It would be much nicer if I could query an entity against a restriction without hitting the database. Does NHibernate have any facility for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an in-memory collection, why not use [LINQ-to-objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx)?

Comment: I can, and do. But my filter editor that they have already used has created a set of criteria objects that I convert to nhibernate criteria. I suppose I could make an in place test for them, but it would be more work than simply running some nhibernate checker on them.

Comment: @CMP: NHibernate maps relational databases to objects; it's not intender for in-memory queries.